# Which airport is featured in this Delta commercial?

Tags: airline-operations, airport

I just saw [a Delta commercial](https://youtu.be/0qrGOhgLQY8?t=57s) with a plane taking off from a runway with a 16R designation (thus, the plane in the commercial was departing from 34L). Does anyone know where this airport is? Climbing out, there appears to be a large body of water ahead, if that helps!

[image]

I had always heard that [Van Nuys (KVNY)](https://www.airnav.com/airport/KVNY) was the only airport with a 16R/16L runway designation, but the airport in the video isn't Van Nuys.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a video of the commercial, that may help shed more light on the situation.

Comment: There are many airports with 16L/16R, [here's another example](http://www.airport-technology.com/projects/izmir-adnan-menderes-international-airport/izmir-adnan-menderes-international-airport3.html).  Sydney, Narita, Van Nuys.  As reirab points out, there are only 18 possible numbers so this is not surprising.

Comment: Based on @reirab's answer, the [same perspective from Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Paine+Field+Airport/@47.8542716,-122.2842819,528a,20y,357.64h,83.14t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x54900159b82b97fd:0x4e3571c12e342514).

Comment: @reirab is 100% correct, it's Paine Field / Snohomish County International. Source: I am based there, and that's a piece of the Everett Boeing plant on the right side. :) You can see Hat/Guemes Island and a piece of Camano Island, as mentioned, and the lights of Everett at the far top right.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've actually had a VIP tour of that Boeing facility because a friend of mine is an engineer there. I flew up in my C-172, but now can't recall which airport I landed at! If I remember correctly, it was a small GA airport ...

Answer (score 10):

It's **[Paine Field (KPAE)](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KPAE) in Seattle**. It has both 16L and 16R and has water (the Puget Sound) directly ahead if you're taking off from the 34s. 34L is also the only runway there large enough for most jet traffic, so that's what a Delta jet would be using if it were there.

It's also worth noting that this commercial is about flight testing and Paine Field just so happens to be the home of an aircraft production facility for some little company named 'Boeing.' You can see their [Everett Production Facility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_Everett_Factory) on the North side of the airport in the Google Earth view and the aerial photo below. Interesting fact: that facility, originally built in 1967 to produce the Boeing 747, [remains the largest building in the world by volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_buildings_in_the_world#Largest_usable_space) even to today. It's 79% larger than the next largest building and a full 3.63 times the size of NASA's [Vehicle Assembly Building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Assembly_Building), the previous largest building in the world by volume, where NASA performed final integration of the Saturn V and Space Shuttle stacks and where it will do so for the SLS.

Here's the Google Earth view, and it looks like the two islands on the left in the commercial are Hat Island and Camano Island:

[image: Google Earth view of Paine Field]

[image: Sectional chart showing KPAE and Puget Sound]
Sectional Chart Showing KPAE

[image: Paine Field - Aerial View]
Aerial View of Paine Field - Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Aerial_Paine_Field_August_2009.jpg)

---

Honestly, the claim of there only being 1 airport with any given runway number seems rather suspicious, since there are only 18 possibilities. Granted, the requirement of having parallel runways makes it a little less unlikely, but still many (if not most) large airports have parallel runways.

Comment: And with many areas having prevailing winds out of the North East or South West, a 16/32 runway setup seems likely to be fairly common.

Comment: @JonStory Did you really mean to say 16/32. I suspect that's a typo. Also on the U.S. west coast a 16/34 runway is a true north-south runway due to the the magnetic variation of appoximately 20E.

Comment: I meant 16/34 as British runways don't use 320 degree circles :p it was indeed a typo. In much of the world 16/34 would be northeast/southwest to some degree

Comment: @JonStory With no magnetic declination, heading 340 would be Northwest, not Northeast. With the declination on the U.S. east coast, Paine's 16-34 runways are actually almost exactly North-South (179/359 true heading.)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and answers! When I said "there was only one airport with 16R/16L designation," I should have clarified that that was in the USA. There is a film about Van Nuys airport called "16 Right," and it tells about the history of KVNY. Perhaps they said it was the only GA airport with twin runways of that designation, and I misheard!  Hmmm... Now I'll have to watch it again!

Comment: @Spencer Even in just the USA, it seems a little dubious. There are **over nineteen thousand** airports in the USA alone (with 18,762 of those being GA as of last year's data from the [Bureau of Transportation Statistics](http://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_statistics/html/table_01_03.html) .)

Comment: Thanks Reirab!  Those stats alone are great "factoids!"  I totally agree it sounds dubious given those numbers, but then again most GA airports aren't really busy enough to justify parallel runways, so maybe it is factual, if you consider just GA in the USA. I'm certainly curious now about the truth, but I really do appreciate your feedback! 

Comment: @Spencer You're welcome! Just from a quick search [KHEF](https://www.airnav.com/airport/KHEF) is another (98%) GA example with a 16-34 L/R runway configuration. It's about 20 miles WSW of D.C. There were a few others I noticed that had mostly GA traffic, but also some commercial and/or military traffic, like [this one in Fort Worth](https://www.airnav.com/airport/AFW) and [this one in Eugene, Oregon](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KEUG).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again! You've put far more effort into it than I would've expected, but it's appreciated! I'm going to have to watch that damn movie again (16-Right)... Hmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can find the full list of [runway data for the US here (as provided by the FAA)](http://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/airportdata_5010/menu/#datadownloads)

They list (confirmed on google maps to see whats actually painted on the tarmac)

- DEN (Denver)
- SEA (Seattle-Tacome)

There may be others as well you can check the list for a more complete overview.

Comment: In addition, Eugene Airport in Oregon also has 16R/16L runways. Outside USA, at least the two airport in Tokyo (Haneda & Narita), Sydney, as well as Roma Fiumicino have the designation.